# Shadows won´t dissapear even with Light

Tags: rendering, texturing, shadows

I applied a texture on a UV Sphere. But it has a shadow on it, even though I placed 3-4 Light sources.
It seems like the shadow is moving with the camera. I can not figure out why and how.
Do you know what this is? Screenshots below

[image]

[image]

Here is the wetransfer link with the Files:
[we.tl/t-XF3ej9V6hx](https://we.tl/t-XF3ej9V6hx)

Updated Link with the screenshots and the Texture:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c1242365d72957744ac6dac7de118fc820230811114808/133c22640cb585327203c2f323fff82920230811114826/fc24c5

Comment: Hello could you please pack the images and share the file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure, but with the File, the size is too big. max. 30 MB

Comment: I can provide a wetranfer link if you want

Comment: Yes please copy paste the wetranfer link

Comment: Hey, sry it took this long. I wasn´t home during the past few days. But here is the wetransfer link with the Files. https://we.tl/t-XF3ej9V6hx

Comment: You didn't pack the images, tbut the problem is probably that you have a weird setup of 3 nodes: Displacement > Bump > Normal Map??!!???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned @moonboots you do have a weird set of nodes.

[image]

Plus, they have quite exaggerated values (like the Bump node's 139 distance).

You also seem to use twice the same texture, so you could just remove the second node and plug the first one in the roughness socket. The color ramp inverts the texture's color, but as we will see later: it isn't needed there.

### Normal input in Principled BSDF

Principled BSDF's Normal input controls the normal of the shader on a per-pixel basis and is meant to fake 3D shape.
The Bump works from a black and white texture and interprets it as elevation, while the Normal Map works from a RGB texture where each pixels represents a XYZ orientation.
The Displacement node is similar to the Bump as it takes a black and white texture and interprets it as elevation, but it is meant to actually deform the geometry and is plugged in the Material Output node's Displacement input.

There are only two nodes you should connect between a texture and the Principled BSDF's Normal input: the Bump node or the Normal Map node.

In your case, your texture is a black and white data, so I would keep only the Bump node, and give it more reasonable values.

Height reads black as the lowest point and white as highest by default. If your texture uses a different system, that's where the Midlevel setting us changed. It is by default set to 0.5, and in some rare cases needs 0 or 1.
Your texture seems to use the default height representation, so not only the Midlevel should be 0.5, but you also do not need to invert the texture with your color ramp.

[image]

### Displacement

If you want to displace the geometry, plug in the Displacement node where it belongs.

By default, it is treated as a Bump Node and will look weird if used while using another Bump Node. You could either remove the Bump node and set the shader's Displacement settings to do both displacement and bump, but you can't control them independently, or you keep the Bump node and set the Displacement setting to do only displacement.

Personally I like to keep both things independent for control. Regardless of your preference, you find this setting in the sidebar > Options tab > Settings Panel > Surface subpanel, set the Displacement to "*Displacement Only*" or "*Displacement And Bump*".

Displacement needs mesh density, so you need to add a subdivision modifier, and play with the displacement node's scale

[image]

### Final Result

This is the final result with subdivision level 4:

[image]

Good to note for the next time you need to post a blend file online for help:

- remove everything not related to the issue
- If you need to ship textures: File > External Data > Pack Resources
- If you need to ship linked files or libraries: File > External Data > Pack Libraries
- Save as a new compressed file : File > Save As > enable Compress in the sidebar before saving

This way I got a 10MB file with your textures included that can be uploaded on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/), instead of your 136MB file without texture. No need to make a zip file with extra screenshots, screenshots are for your question.

---

To learn more:

- [Principled BSDF — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html)
- [Bump Node — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/bump.html)
- [Displacement Node — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/displacement.html)
- [Normal Map Node — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/normal_map.html)

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help! I updated my first post with a new updated wetransfer link. The Texture and a few screenshots are included in the zip file. I will try to adjust the settings as you described.

Comment: I update my answer with new screenshots and details, but it's the right solution.